# character encoding in linux systems

Tags: linux, character-encoding

I have web page its charset is 8859-9 and it was prepared in windows with char encoding ascii. from ftp access, I am opening it via gedit in ubuntu then turkish chars changes like (turkish ı became ý). 
what can I do to avoid this kind of stupid things?

Comment: Same question, same author: http://askubuntu.com/questions/56668/character-encoding-in-ubuntu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried setting your locale to `tr_TR.ISO-8859-9`

To find out what your current locale is, use the `locale` command with no arguments. It will print the values of all of the relevant environment variables except for LANGUAGE. `locale charmap` prints the name of the current encoding. To find out what locales are available, type `locale -a`. To find out what encodings are available, type `locale -m`.

If you use gedit's file-open dialogue you can choose an appropriate encoding for the file you are opening.

If the above doesn't help, please update your question with the output of `file filename` and ten **relevant** lines of output of `hexdump -C filename`

> what can I do to avoid this kind of stupid things?

Use utf-8 for everything everywhere at all times. Convert anything that isn't utf-8 into utf-8 using `iconv` or `recode`. Make sure all the fonts you use support the [scripts](http://www.unicode.org/charts/#scripts) you use (i.e. have glyphs for the relevant unicode ranges).

Comment: thanks it works in fedora. when I open the file from ftp remote serve. chars are in correct shape.

Answer (score 2):

You can convert with `iconv`:

```
$ iconv -f iso-8859-1 -t utf-8 somefile.latin1 > somefile.utf8

$
```

An alternative to `iconv` is to `recode`. If not already known, you can find out the charset with the `file` command:

```
$ file somefile.latin1
somefile.latin1: ISO-8859 text

$
```